# Recursively Inverting a linear system - getting huge errors (precision)

Tags: r, optimization, linear-algebra, precision, numerical-methods

I have a Ax =b type linear system - where A is an upper-triangular matrix. The structure of A is defined as follows:

```
    comp.Amat <- function(i,j,prob) ifelse(i > j, 0, dbinom(x=i, size=j, prob=prob))

    prob <- 1/4
    A <- outer(1:50, 1:50 , FUN=function(r,c) comp.Amat(r,c,prob) )
```

The entries in A are binomial probabilities - and the issue is the diagonal entries fastly approach to 0 when the size of A grows.

If we define the vector b as follows as well:

```
    b <- seq(1,50,1);
```

Then solve(a=A,b=b) - gives an error:

```
    "  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.07584e-64"
```

That makes sense, since the diagonal entries are almost 0, so the matrix becomes non-invertible.

As a work-around, I have written the following recursive function - which starts to compute  the value of last diagonal entry, then replaces that value in the previous rows. Since each   entry in matrix is **dbinom(j,i, prob)** for j=>i :I can get a solution via this way.

```
    solve.for.x.custom <- function(A, b, prob)
    {

      n =length(A[1,])
      m =length(A[,1])

      x = seq(1,n, 1);
      x[x> 0] = -1000;

      calc.inv.Aii <- function(i,j, prob)
      {
        res = (1 / (prob*(1-prob)))^i;
        return(res);


      }

      for (i in m:1 )
      {

        if(i ==m)
        {
  rhs =0;

        }else
        {
          rhs=0;
          for(j in m:(i+1))
          {
            rhs =  dbinom(x=i,size=j,prob=prob)*x[j] + rhs;
          }

        }

        x[i] = (b[i] - rhs)*calc.inv.Aii(i,i);

      }
      print(x)
      return(x)

    }
```

My problem is - when I multiply this solution *x'* by matrix A, the errors (Ax'- b) are huge. Since I have an analytical solution (each entry in x_i can be described as a in terms of binomial probabilities multiplies by previous values) - the error I should get is 0- in each row.

I see that (1 / (1/a)) may not be equal to a because of these issues. However, the current errors are really big( -1.13817489781529e+168).

```
    x_prime=solve.for.x.custom(A, b, prob)
    A%*%x_prime - b
    #output
                    [,1]
     [1,] -1.13817489781529e+168
     [2,]  2.11872209742428e+167
     [3,] -1.58403954589004e+166
     [4,]  6.52328959209082e+164
     [5,] -1.69562573261261e+163
     [6,]  3.00614551450976e+161
    ***
    [49,]  -7.58010305220250e+08
    [50,]   9.65162608741321e+03
```

I would really appreciate it you'd recommend any suggestions or efficient methods. I gave the size of A and b as 50 -but I intend to grow them as well thus in that case this the error will increase also.

Answer (score 2):

If your matrix `A` is upper triangular you probably want to use `backsolve(A, b)` rather than `solve(A, b)`.

---

You can do arbitrary precision in R with [`Rmpfr`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/), which will require writing a compatible version of `backsolve`.  With the code below the break we can get

```
> print(max(abs(b - .b)), digits=5)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  1024   bits 
[1] 2.9686e-267
```

There is one important caveat though: the values in `A` may not be accurate enough since they come from `dbinom` rather than using `mpfr` objeccts. Depending on your end goal, you may need to write your own version of `dbinom` using `Rmpfr`.

---

```
library(Rmpfr)

logcomp.Amat <- function(i,j,prob) ifelse(i > j, -Inf, dbinom(x=i, size=j, prob=prob, log=TRUE))

nbits <- 1024

.backsolve <- function(A, b) {

    n <- length(b)
    x <- mpfr(numeric(n), nbits)

    for(i in rev(seq_len(n))) {

        known <- i + seq_len(n - i)
        z <- if(length(known) > 0) sum(A[i,known] * x[known]) else 0

        x[i] <- (b[i] - z) / A[i,i]
    }

    return(x)
}

logA <- outer(1:50, 1:50, logcomp.Amat, prob=1/4)
b <- 1:50

A <- exp(mpfr(logA, nbits))
b <- mpfr(b, nbits)

x <- .backsolve(A, b)

.b <- as.vector(A %*% x)
```

Comment: With the above edit to comp.Amat, and this code: x <- backsolve(A,b) ;  max(abs(A %*% x - b)), I get this result: [1] 7.805534e+25.  This is a very ill-conditioned system, and I suspect that this is the point of the exercise.

Comment: Thank you @pete - this helped decrease the error. But the error that I get is still really high..

Comment: @MatthewLundberg yes I get the same result as well. That error is still really high though:(

Comment: The size of the values in `A` and `x` might be manageable on the log-scale.

Comment: Worth noting that `max(abs(b1 - b) / x)` gives very small numbers (i.e. the relative error in `x` is probably very small). It may not be possible to store the "correct" answers to sufficient precision to recover `b` from `A` and `x`.